# Cannot select PDF files in Chrome iOS using Dropbox

Tags: ios, wordpress, google-chrome, dropbox

I have an issue using Wordpress's Media Manager whilst using iOS **Chrome** browser. It won't allow me to select any **PDF** files. It works fine in Safari but was wondering if there is any restrictions on Chrome, Dropbox or iOS which is stopping a user from selecting it.

I have checked that all the correct "accepted types" are correct. I'm sure it's not that. (Wordpress has added .pdf and application/pdf to type="file")

**Code:**
 iOS Chrome (59.0.3071.102)  This is the exact code for our File Input:

```
<input id="html5_1bka" type="file" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg,.jpg,.jpeg,.jpe,image/gif,.gif,image/png,.png,image/bmp,.bmp,image/tiff,.tiff,.tif,.ico,.asf,.asx,video/x-ms-wmv,.wmv,.wmx,.wm,video/avi,.avi,.divx,video/x-flv,.flv,video/quicktime,.mov,.qt,video/mpeg,.mpeg,.mpg,.mpe,video/mp4,.mp4,video/x-m4v,.m4v,video/ogg,.ogv,video/webm,.webm,video/x-matroska,.mkv,video/3gpp,.3gp,.3gpp,video/3gpp2,.3g2,.3gp2,text/plain,.txt,.asc,.c,.cc,.h,.srt,text/csv,.csv,.tsv,.ics,.rtx,text/css,.css,text/html,.htm,.html,.vtt,.dfxp,audio/mpeg,.mp3,audio/x-m4a,.m4a,.m4b,.ra,.ram,audio/x-wav,.wav,audio/ogg,.ogg,.oga,.mid,.midi,audio/x-ms-wma,.wma,.wax,.mka,text/rtf,.rtf,application/x-javascript,.js,application/pdf,.pdf,.class,.tar,application/zip,.zip,.gz,.gzip,.rar,.7z,image/photoshop,.psd,.xcf,application/msword,.doc,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,.pot,.pps,.ppt,.wri,.xla,application/vnd.ms-excel,.xls,.xlt,.xlw,.mdb,.mpp,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,.docx,.docm,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template,.dotx,.dotm,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,.xlsx,.xlsm,.xlsb,.xltx,.xltm,.xlam,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation,.pptx,.pptm,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow,.ppsx,.ppsm,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template,.potx,.potm,.ppam,.sldx,.sldm,.onetoc,.onetoc2,.onetmp,.onepkg,.oxps,.xps,.odt,.odp,.ods,.odg,.odc,.odb,.odf,.wp,.wpd,.key,.numbers,.pages,.bz2,.jpeg,.jpg,.mp4,.onetoc,.ppt,.tgz,.txz,.txt,.wpd,.xz,.jpe">
```

**Screen shots:**
[image]

[image]

I've seen another site working and looking at the code I could see that they didn't specify an "accept" attribute. I remove it and tested. It still doesn't allow PDF selection. Totally stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **removing all the file types** in the accept attribute. Removing the entire attribute altogether didn't work for me.

Your input html should now look like:

```
<input id="html5_1bka" type="file" multiple="" accept="">
```

In order to fix this in Wordpress you might have to write a bit of custom JS to listen for **wp.media**, **open** event

[How to Trigger some JavaScript when Media Popup is opened?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124005/is-it-possible-to-trigger-some-javascript-when-media-popup-is-opened)